# Split texture image in threejs

Tags: three.js

I am working on displaying cubemap panoramas using three.js I have the panorama in this format stacked in one image:

[cubemap panorama](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOr9q.jpg)

I load this image using `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url)` then I was able to display it by modifying the `faceVertexUvs` array as described in this [tutorial](http://solutiondesign.com/blog/-/blogs/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mappi-1/) but I forced to use `sampler2D` for the texture and texture2D in the fragment shader with uv coordinates.

But I want to use `textureCube` function in the fragment shader (as it takes a direction vector which I need to perform some trick) so I need a `samplerCube` variable whose value is a texture with array of 6 separated images for each face of the cube.

So How can I split the image texture into 6 images?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no way to easily split an image in WebGL. You could possibly use rendering to texture to draw every side of a cubemap, but I think using canvas would be easier.

```
var cubemapImage, // the cubemap
    cubemapSize, // size of a side of the cubemap
    posXImageCtx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    negXImageCtx, posYImageCtx, /* etc */;

posXImageCtx.canvas.width = posXImageCtx.canvas.height = cubemapSize;
posXImageCtx.drawImage(
    cubemapImage,
    0, 0,
    cubemapSize, cubemapSize,
    0, 0,
    cubemapSize, cubemapSize
);

/* by analogy other sides */

var cubemap = new THREE.CubeTexture([
        posXImageCtx.canvas,
        negXImageCtx.canvas,
        posYImageCtx.canvas,
        /* etc */
    ], /* ... */);
```